# How do I gain access to a repository in a custom ValidationAttribute?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, autofac

```
public class UniqueNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string UniqueNameViolationMessage = "This name is already taken. Please select another.";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //return somerepo.IsUniqueName(name)
        //how do I get access to repo here?  Tried DI with autofac but it came out as null
    }
}
```

I'm using dependency injection to inject repositories into my Web API.  However, it seems I cannot inject into a ValidationAttribute.  It comes out as null if I try to inject.  I'm using Autofac for DI.  Is there another way I can gain access to my repo?

Note that I am only using Web API, not MVC, so I cannot use the MVC DependencyResolver.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyRepository>().As<IMyRepository>().InstancePerRequest();

var container = builder.Build();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver((IContainer)container); ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC 4 Custom ValidationAttribute Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219408/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-validationattribute-dependency-injection)

Comment: The solution to that question was to use the MVC DependencyResolver.  I am only using Web API here.

Comment: can you try using `validationContext.ServiceContainer.GetService(typeof(IService))` ?

Comment: I tried using that line but received null.  Perhaps I'm registering my type incorrectly?  I've posted my code for registering the DependencyResolver.  I apologize if it is something obvious I am a beginner and am wrapping my head around DI and Autofac.

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you are after as the validation attribute is instantiated by the framework logic and not your DI container.  I worked around this by explicitly calling the validation logic, if you do that then what @CyrilDurand suggested will work as you create your own ValidationContext which can have any service injected into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're missing this line:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
var container = builder.Build();
```

And rather than inherit from `IActionFilter`, inherit from `IAutofacActionFilter`.

More details here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#provide-filters-via-dependency-injection